# Highcharts - problem when dividing series

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts and have to divide a series, so the mouse over event focus on the correct data. But, when I divide the data, the space between horizontal series changes.

[Highcharts one serie - before divide the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNciB.png)

[Highcharts multiple series - after divide the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaqMM.png)

I also have the two playgrounds on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6g09hjyk/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
},
credits: false,

navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
        theme: {
            fill: 'white',
            padding: 5,
            stroke: 'none'
        }
    }
},

title: {
    text: null
},

subtitle: {
},

xAxis: [{
    visible: true,
    offset: 0.1,
},
{
    visible: false
}],
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointWidth: -5
    }
},

yAxis: [{
    visible: true,
    reversed: true,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'MD (m)',
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    },
    min: 2000,
    max: 6500
},
{
    opposite: true,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
        text: null,
    }
}
],

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [
    {
        showInLegend: false,
        pointPlacement: 0,
        animation: {
            duration: 2000
        },
        pointWidth: 4,
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: false,
        name: 'Revestimento',
        color: 'grey',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            crop: false,
            x: 0
        },
        data: [
            [2001, 2057, 3455],
            [2002, 2059, 5499],
            [2003, 2055, 5838],
            [2004, 2058, 6028],
            [2007, 2058, 6028],
            [2008, 2055, 5838],
            [2009, 2059, 5499],
            [2010, 2057, 3455]
        ]
    }
]
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/6g09hjyk/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
},
credits: false,

navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
        theme: {
            fill: 'white',
            padding: 5,
            stroke: 'none'
        }
    }
},

title: {
    text: null
},

subtitle: {
},

xAxis: [{
    visible: true,
    offset: 0.1,
},
{
    visible: false
}],
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointWidth: -5
    }
},

yAxis: [{
    visible: true,
    reversed: true,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'MD (m)',
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    },
    min: 2000,
    max: 6500
},
{
    opposite: true,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
        text: null,
    }
}
],

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [
    {
        showInLegend: false,
        pointPlacement: 0,
        animation: {
            duration: 2000
        },
        pointWidth: 4,
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: false,
        name: 'Revestimento',
        color: 'grey',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            crop: false,
            x: 0
        },
        data: [
            [2001, 2057, 3455],
            [2010, 2057, 3455]
        ]
    },
    {
        showInLegend: false,
        pointPlacement: 0,
        animation: {
            duration: 2000
        },
        pointWidth: 4,
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: false,
        name: 'Revestimento',
        color: 'grey',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            crop: false,
            x: 0
        },
        data: [
            [2002, 2059, 5499],
            [2009, 2059, 5499]]
    },
    {
        showInLegend: false,
        pointPlacement: 0,
        animation: {
            duration: 2000
        },
        pointWidth: 4,
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: false,
        name: 'Revestimento',
        color: 'grey',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            crop: false,                
            x: 0
        },
        data: [
            [2003, 2055, 5838],
            [2008, 2055, 5838],
        ]
    },
    {
        showInLegend: false,
        pointPlacement: 0,
        animation: {
            duration: 2000
        },
        pointWidth: 4,
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: false,
        name: 'Revestimento',
        color: 'grey',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            crop: false,
            x: 0
        },
        data: [
            [2004, 2058, 6028],
            [2007, 2058, 6028],
        ]
    }
]
```

});

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the `grouping` feature:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      ...,
      grouping: false
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rta5xs81/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.columnrange.grouping